# Normal subgroup in Dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do you show that {$ 1,a,a^{2}, ..., a^{n-1} $} is a normal subgroup of the nth dihedral group? I thought maybe it is the only subgroup of n elements , so then it's a normal subgroup. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Any subgroup of index 2 is a normal subgroup (suppose not, see what happens).

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove it directly: the dihedral group is generated by $a$ together with a reflection $r$, so all you need to do is to show that $ra^kr^{-1}\in \langle a\rangle$.